Designing a customized, life-sized model/copy of flower vase
I am a noob! I am trying to create an anniversary a present. I want to create a life-sized LEGO, customized vase, that was given to me as a present.
I plan on putting Lego flowers in the vase. I have no idea how to begin. I have a picture of the vase I am trying to recreate but I cannot find any help on the internet on how to start from scratch: to determine which bricks (size, color, etc) I will need and step-by-step instructions for making the hour-glass shaped vase.

Can you please edit your question and add a photo of the vase you want to reproduce? Also keep in mind that curved shapes are difficult to replicate, and the available parts will be limited.

It is unlikely to get a fully build model as an answer. But we could help with some suggestions if you present your "work in progress" model.

You could have a look through existing flower vase MOCs to see if any of them strike you, or give you inspiration. One good site for that is rebrickable. Some of the designs have free instructions, others are paid. The site also helps you in buying the parts needed if desired.

If the vase needs to be water-tight, then using LEGO bricks alone will not be sufficient, as their tolerances do not result in water-tight walls.
But if you plan to put only LEGO flowers inside, you don't need this requirement and can proceed to plan the vase. By your account it is hourglass-shaped, which means a series of circles of varying diameters stacked on each other.
To plan the circles for the layers, there are various methods listed in this article, but the easiest and cheapest one is to use standard bricks and go for a blocky (Minecraft-like) look:

In order to ensure a proper connection, each layer should ideally be planned as two circles of similar diameter - so for example if at one point the vase should transition from a 9-diameter to a 10-diameter circle, then build the second layer to occupy both a 9 and a 10-diameter circle. This way it can be securely attached to the 9-diameter of the first level (which might or might not have an 8-diameter inside to provide connection to the underlying layer).
If you do the planning in Stud.io, you can generate building instructions natively from the tool and also can buy the required parts from Bricklink directly.
